# Нужно ли проверять SQLiteDatabase db на null?

Tags: android, sqlite, null

В своем андроид-приложении ни разу не проверял `db != null`, при этом запросы работают. Прочитал, что надо проверять, к примеру, как в следующем коде.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new ContactDbHelper(
        getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
if (db != null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "DB Contacts is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error create database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Вопрос такой, нужно ли проверять `SQLiteDatabase db` на `null`? Это просто подстраховка и если да, по каким причинам БД может не создаться, при условии, что код рабочий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код открытия БД ищет БД по пути задаваемому методом `Context.getDatabasePath()`, легко может случиться, что какая-то сволочь однажды решит перегрузить этот метод в своем `Activity` и указать путь на внешний носитель - тогда вас будет ждать легкий [Überraschung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberraschung) :)

Так что проверять надо все таки.

Comment: Интересно конечно, но немного не улавливаю. Разве БД не автономна для каждого приложения (не предполагающая раздачу)? Какое отношение чей-то активити может иметь к БД, к примеру, моего приложения?

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что вы сами или член вашей команды в вашей аппе может поменять `getDatabasePath()`